# Remove added error information from response

Tags: flask, error-handling, flask-restplus

Using flask-restplus I've noticed that if I handle some error like:

```
api.abort(code=404, message='Item not found')
```

The response renders:

```
{
  "message": "Item not found. You have requested this URI [/item/1]
              but did you mean /item/<item_id> ?"
}
```

I really don't want that extra bit of information but can't find a way to remove it.

Is there one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, there is a config flag for this. [Reported here](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/67#issuecomment-120401088)

```
ERROR_404_HELP=False
```

Does the trick